# Inequality constraints in systemfit

Tags: r

I'm trying to estimate a simultaneous equations system using `systemfit`, but cannot seem to specify inequalities as constraints. I've recreated the problem using the `airquality` dataset, the issue arises when adding inequalities to the `restrict.matrix` argument. Is there any workaround to get this example to work?

```
require(systemfit)

lagAQ <- rbind(NA, airquality[1:nrow(airquality)-1,])
colnames(lagAQ) <- paste("lag", colnames(lagAQ), sep = "")
data <- data.frame(airquality, lagAQ)

eqOzone <- Ozone ~ lagOzone + lagWind + lagTemp
eqWind  <- Wind ~ lagOzone + lagWind + lagTemp
eqTemp  <- Temp ~ lagOzone + lagWind + lagTemp

airSystem <- list(ozone = eqOzone, wind = eqWind, temp = eqTemp)

constr <- c("ozone_(Intercept) = 0",
            "wind_(Intercept) = 0",
            "temp_(Intercept) = 0",

            "ozone_lagOzone > 0",
            "ozone_lagWind > 0",
            "ozone_lagTemp > 0",

            "ozone_lagOzone + wind_lagOzone + temp_lagOzone = 1",
            "ozone_lagWind + wind_lagWind + temp_lagWind = 1",
            "ozone_lagTemp + wind_lagTemp + temp_lagTemp = 1"
            )

airModel <- systemfit(airSystem, restrict.matrix = constr, data = data)
```

Comment: you can the answer here , it uses `lpSolveAPI`  package http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976326/constrained-optimization-in-r-setting-up-constraints/13977187#13977187

Comment: If a package doesn't do what you were seeking, then search for another package. In this case I would imagined the CRAN Task View on Optimization would be helpful. I know I have answered question on SO regarding inequality constraints so a search here might pull up something. I use MarkMail for searching rhelp "archives".

Comment: The recommendations you made would be fine if this were a straight optimization problem, however I'm trying to _estimate_ a simultaneous system of equations by OLS on data, and to my knowledge `systemfit` is the only package that allows this (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/systemfit/vignettes/systemfit.pdf).

Comment: Your clarification would be fine if you were posting a linear problem, but you are not. You may be able to recast it as a linear problem but that is beyond my pay grade.